# SVGのPATH要素を、JavaScriptでPOST送信すると、受信内容が[object SVGPathElement]となる

Tags: javascript, svg

**やりたいこと**

- SVGのPATH要素を、JavaScriptでPOST送信
- PHPでPOST受信して利用
- 送信したいPATH要素

  `<path d=" … 中略 … "></path>`

---

**現状**
■JavaScript での送信内容

- フォーム動的生成
- input 要素に、path 要素を格納した target を追加

  elem.setAttribute('value', target);

■動的生成後のHTML内容／コンソール画面

```
<input type="hidden" name="hoge" value="[object SVGPathElement]">
```

■ PHP での POST 受信内容

> [object SVGPathElement]

---

**質問**

`[object SVGPathElement]` ではなく、PATH 要素として受けとるためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

`console.log(target);` では、

```
<path d=" … 中略 … "></path>
```

と表示されるのに、フォームへセットすると、なぜ

```
[object SVGPathElement]
```

になるのでしょうか？

Comment: 本質問は回答により解決しているようですので、そのことを示すためにも回答の承認をよろしくおねがいします。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`path` 要素のタグ自体（`<path>〜</path>`）をそのまま欲しい、という事でしたら、`outerHTML` プロパティを利用することで取得出来ます。

```
<script>
  // 対象となる path を取得
  var target = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
  var path = target.getElementsByTagName('path')[0];

  // path要素が文字列として返る
  console.log(path.outerHTML);
</script>
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。おかげで希望結果を取得することができました！ 大変参考になりましたー

Answer (score 0):

質問の中にはtargetの取得部分の記述はありませんが、  
 **[object SVGPathElement]** はオブジェクト自体を引っ張ってきていると推察できます。

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" id="svg1" >
    <path d="M10,10h10l-5,10z" id="path1" />
    <path d="M10,10h10l-5,10z" id="path2" />
</svg>
```

これだと1つ上のelementを掴んでhtmlごと文字列化したり

> document.getElementById("svg1").innerHTML

パラメータの文字列を個別に取得する必要があると思います。

> document.getElementById("path1").attributes['d'].value

パラメータだけを全部取得するならこの方がいいかな?

```
  var attr1 = document.getElementById("path1").attributes;
  for (var i = 0; i < attr1.length; i++) {
    属性名 = attr1[i].nodeName ;
    値     = attr1[i].value ;
  };
```

他の要素も取得するのであれば場合によって  
**[element].parentNode**や **[element].childNodes**でDOMツリーを辿ってもいいでしょう。

適当ですが例です。

```
var elemSvg = document.getElementById("svg1");
var childSvg = elemSvg.childNodes; 
var arry1 = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < childSvg.length; i++) {
    if (childSvg[i].attributes){
        var attr1 = childSvg[i].attributes;
        for (var j = 0; j < attr1.length; j++) {
            arry1.push(childSvg[i].nodeName+':'+attr1[j].nodeName+':'+attr1[j].value);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。具体的なコードを記載いただき、大変参考になりました。DOMツリーは難しそうなのでこれまで敬遠していたのですが、やっぱり勉強しなければ、と改めて思いましたー